# How to copy data (f.e. address ) with copy button in one View ? C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, view, copy

My problem: I don't have any idea how to write the `CopyAddress` method.

I want to fill `StreetName`, click button to fill `CorespondenceStreetName`  automatically.

I use:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

and have an `Address` model class:

```
    public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string CorespondenceStreetName { get; set; }
    }
```

and a view:

```
@model CRM.Models.Address

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Address"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetName, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label"})
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
         </div>

         <a type="button" class="btn" href="@Url.Action("CopyAddress", "Address")">
         <span>Copy from Main</span>
         </a>

        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CorespondenceStreetName , htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label"})
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CorespondenceStreetName , new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You would be better to use JavaScript to do this rather than posting back to the server.

Comment: @marc_s thx a lot for editing !

Comment: Then I used JS :                                                                  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#buttonAddressCopy').click(function() {
 $('#coresStreetName').val($('#mainStreetName').val());
       });
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Script is so simple :D

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonAddressCopy').click(function() {
        $('#coresStreetName').val($('#mainStreetName').val());
    });
});
```